# Evitar valores repetidos en vectores c++

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda para resolver lo siguiente: necesito hacer un vector nuevo de nombres de juguetes sin que se repitan. Este vector hay que hacerlo con base en varias cajas que tienen sus juguetes, pueden haber repetidos, entonces hay que descartarlos. He tratado con esto, sin embargo, en la parte del if, me falla la lógica para poder descartar los repetidos y agregar los no repetidos.

```
vector<string> juguetes;
string aux = "";
juguetes.push_back(caja->at(0).getVectorDeJuguetes()->at(0)->getNombreJuguete());

for (unsigned i = 0; i < caja->size(); i++) {
    
    for (unsigned k = 0; k < caja->at(i).getVectorDeJuguetes()->size(); k++) {
        
        aux = caja->at(i).getVectorDeJuguetes()->at(k)->getNombreJuguete();

        for (unsigned j = 0; j < juguetes.size(); j++) {

            if (juguetes.at(j) == aux) {
                break;
            }
            else {
                juguetes.push_back(aux);
            }
        }
    }
}

cout << juguetes.size();
```

Answer (score 2):

Tal y como lo tienes, solo te compara con el primer elemento del vector. Si no es igual, lo insertas.

Ya sabrás que eso no es válido, que tienes que recorrer el vector completo :-)

```
unsigned j;

for( j = 0; j < juguetes.size( ); ++j ) {
    if( juguetes.at( j ) == aux ) { break; }
}

if( j == juguetes.size( ) ) {
    // No está. Insertamos.
    juguetes.push_back(aux);
}
```

Ya que usas un indice para recorrer el vector, podemos usarlo. Recorres el vector hasta que encuentres el mismo nombre o hasta que llegues al final, lo que pase antes.

Una vez fuera del bucle, usamos el indice. Si se ha llegado hasta el final del vector durante la búsqueda, es que el nombre no estaba. Y lo insertamos.